# Mocked EhCache NullPointerException in JUnit 5 test

Tags: java, junit, mockito, ehcache

I am writing Unit tests for a service I want to test. Several methods try to retrieve values from an `EhCache`. 
I tried mocking them with `Mockito` and simply have the `get(String key)` method of `Cache` return null, since I want to ignore the caching for these tests.

My test class:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.anyBoolean;
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.anyList;
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.anyString;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.times;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.Resource;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;

import com.jysk.dbl.esldataservice.model.Preis;
import com.jysk.dbl.esldataservice.service.PreisService;
import com.jysk.dbl.esldataservice.service.external.PimDataService;
import com.jysk.dbl.esldataservice.service.external.SapCarService;

import net.sf.ehcache.Cache;
import net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager;

public class PreisServiceTest {

    @Mock
    private SapCarService sapCarService;
    @Mock
    private ArticleDataService articleDataService;
    @Mock
    private CacheManager cacheManager;
    @Mock
    private Cache cache;

    @InjectMocks
    @Resource
    private PreisService preisService;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setup() {

        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

        when(this.cacheManager.getCache(anyString())).thenReturn(this.cache);
        when(this.cache.get(anyString())).then(null);
    }

    protected static final String TEST_STORE_IDENTIFIER = "1234";
    private static final String ARTICLE_IDENTIFIER_1 = "12345001";
    private static final String ARTICLE_IDENTIFIER_2 = "54321001";

    private final Preis p1 = new Preis(ARTICLE_IDENTIFIER_1, 10.00, 15.00, "01", "01", "01");
    private final Preis p2 = new Preis(ARTICLE_IDENTIFIER_2, 20.00, 25.00, "02", "02", "02");

    @Test
    void testGetPreisReturnsOneCorrectPreis() {

        when(this.sapCarService.getPreise(Arrays.asList(ARTICLE_IDENTIFIER_1), TEST_STORE_IDENTIFIER, true)).thenReturn(Arrays.asList(this.p1));

        final List<Preis> actual = this.preisService.getPreis(ARTICLE_IDENTIFIER_1, TEST_STORE_IDENTIFIER);

        verify(this.sapCarService, times(1)).getPreise(anyList(), anyString(), anyBoolean());

        assertNotNull(actual);
        assertEquals(1, actual.size());
        assertEquals(this.p1, actual);
    }
}
```

My implementation:

```
private Preis searchPreisInCache(String key) {

    final Element preisOptional = this.cacheManager.getCache("preis").get(key); // NPE here
    if (preisOptional != null) {

        final Preis preis = (Preis) preisOptional.getObjectValue();
        logger.info(String.format("Preis with key '%s' found in cache 'preis'.", key));
        return preis;
    }
    return null;
}
```

The stackTrace showed, that the NPE gets thrown inside the `net.sf.ehcache.Cache` class:

```
public final Element get(Object key) throws IllegalStateException, CacheException {
    getObserver.begin(); // NPE thrown here
    checkStatus();

    if (disabled) {
        getObserver.end(GetOutcome.MISS_NOT_FOUND);
        return null;
    }

    Element element = compoundStore.get(key);
    if (element == null) {
        getObserver.end(GetOutcome.MISS_NOT_FOUND);
        return null;
    } else if (isExpired(element)) {
        tryRemoveImmediately(key, true);
        getObserver.end(GetOutcome.MISS_EXPIRED);
        return null;
    } else if (!skipUpdateAccessStatistics(element)) {
        element.updateAccessStatistics();
    }
    getObserver.end(GetOutcome.HIT);
    return element;
}
```

Is there any easy solution for this problem, if I simply want the `Cache` to return `null`, whenever it's called?

Comment: Getting an NPE in the `Cache` is an indication that your class under test is not using a mock since its actual implementation is executed, which in turn indicates that the `CacheManager` instance is not a mock either. How do you obtain the instance of `CacheManager` in your implementation. Also, can you please post your complete test including imports and class annotations (if any)?

Comment: I get it with `@Autowired`. I also have a simple `ehcache.xml` configuration file. I will also edit my question to include my complete test class.

Comment: I just debugged a bit and saw that the instance of `cache` is of type `Cache$MockitoMock` and `cacheManager` is `CacheManager$MockitoMock`. So they are indeed mocks.

Comment: Well if they're mocks then the logic inside should be skipped, right? Can you try breaking at the  `getObserver.begin(); // NPE thrown here` and see in what case the line gets executed?

Comment: It gets exeuted from the `when(this.cache.get(anyString())).then(null);` line inside the `setup()` method.

Comment: Does it still appear to be a mock instance?

Comment: Yes, the `Cache` instance is still a mock.

Comment: Then how come its original implementation gets executed? Something does not add-up... please double check the call stack while debugging. If it's a mock then its behavior should be _"redefined"_ with whatever you configure via mockito, thus none of its old behavior should be triggered.

Comment: Could it be, that it's not working because the method from `Cache` is final?

Comment: Good catch! That could be a reason. Traditionally Mockito 1.x was not able to mock final method/classes and you'd resort to [PowerMockito](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Mockito) for these tasks. In [v2.x it is now possible](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/What%27s-new-in-Mockito-2#unmockable), so you have a couple of options depending on your version

Comment: Thanks, the opt-in mocking of final methods works perfectly! Would you please post your commend as an answer, so that I can accept it?

Comment: No problem. Under the circumstances I believe the glory is all yours. Feel free to post an answer with your findings and solution and chose it as the correct one.

Comment: Well then thanks again for the help. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Mockito` can't mock `final` methods and classes without some configuration. As Morfic pointed out, it is posible with `Mockito` v2.x, like explained [here](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/What%27s-new-in-Mockito-2#unmockable) and [here](https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-final).

Basically, you have to add a text file named `org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker` under the directory `src/test/resources/mockito-extensions` with the content `mock-maker-inline` and tada, `Mockito` can mock final methods and classes.

However, this uses a different engine with different limitations, so be aware of that.